# toast not displaying

Tags: android, android-activity, toast

I'm using a broadcastreceiver called MyTimeReceiver to display a toast at intervals every hour (every 10 seconds for testing). My problem is that the toast is not displaying.

Here is my code snipped from the main activity file (SafeDrive3Activity):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     //add 10 seconds to calendar object
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SafeDrive3Activity.this,
        0, new Intent(SafeDrive3Activity.this, MyTimeReceiver.class), 0);

      // Schedule the alarm!
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),mAlarmSender);
```

broadcastreceiver class:

```
public class MyTimeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 

{

    @Override

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"HOUNOTIFICATION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         }
```

Please help this has been driving me mad for hours.

Comment: are you registering your receiver in code or manifest?

Comment: <receiver android:name="MyTimeReceiver" android:enabled="true"></receiver>

Comment: Wait... do you have a period in front of that name? If not, put one. ".MyTimeReceiver"

Answer (score 1):

This one is all over the place. You create a `Calendar` you never use, you tell the `AlarmManager` to use the `RTC_WAKEUP` then use the `elapsedRealtime()` time source :).

Try this:

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), mAlarmSender);
```

Comment: i've taken out the calender code:

 mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SafeDrive3Activity.this,
            0, new Intent(SafeDrive3Activity.this, MyTimeReceiver.class), 0);
        
          // Schedule the alarm!
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000*60*10, mAlarmSender);

Comment: any idea how to get the toast in MyTimeReceiver to display every 10 seconds?

Comment: Nvm, just saw your edit. I've replaced -  am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),mAlarmSender); 
WITH - am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), mAlarmSender);

Answer (score 0):

Try this for displaing toast every 10 sec.

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000*10, mAlarmSender));
```